# Command to change the default "repo" in winetricks

Tags: winetricks

I can't explain this well. I was once having problems with vcredist and found a command online that changes your default package source from official, ubuntu approved to newer versions maintained, I think, by the creators of winetricks. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Got it after trawling through dozens upon dozens of google results.

```
sudo winetricks --self-update
```

This is what I was referring to:

```
warning: This will install Winetricks directly from its original developers.
         Debian has no control over that version
```